# Parsing a Text File of IP addresses into an Array with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to parse a text file of IP addresses into an array, all on separate lines, and remove duplicate IP addresses. I'm not exactly sure how I'd do it, but this is how I would start to do it:

```
printf "Enter your list file: "
input = gets.chomp

def parse(input)
    list = File.open(input)
    array = []
    #some code to load the file into the array
    #with the IP addresses on separate lines
    #and remove duplicate IP addresses
end
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction or show me some example code, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def parse(input)
  ip_list = []

  File.open(input, "r") do |infile|
    while (line = infile.gets)
      current_ip = line.strip
      # push in ip_list if not already present in ip_list
      ip_list << current_ip if !ip_list.include?(current_ip) 
    end
  end

  return ip_list
end

printf "Enter your list file: "
input = gets.chomp
puts parse(input)
```

Let me know if it is not what you are asking.